# Trying to send a view's id with an intent. Getting "false"

Tags: android

This class has information that I want to send with an intent to another activity. When the image button "superman" is pressed the onClick() handler sends an intent to SuperheroActivity. But when I try and retrieve that information in the other activity I get "false".

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity implements
    OnClickListener {
private ImageButton superman;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    superman = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.superman);
    superman.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MenuActivity.this, SuperheroActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", v.getId());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

This is the piece of code that tries to retrieve the information from the intent. Note: This is SuperheroActivity.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
id = intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);
// This is just a dirty way for me to see the value of the id I am getting.
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.superheroText); 
text.setText(id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in this line of code.

```
text.setText(id);
```

means the resource id (i.e `String` resource id).
try replacing and using this.

```
text.setText(String.valueOf(id));
```

Comment: setText method is overloaded to take a string resource id as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

***Get the bundle using `getExtras()`***

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
id = intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
```

---

***REMEMBER*** You cant `setText(int)`! the `int` must be a `String`

So change

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.superheroText); 
text.setText(id);
```

to

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.superheroText); 
text.setText(String.valueOf(id)); //change id to a string
```

Comment: setText method is overloaded to take a string resource id as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

use id = intent..getExtras().getInt("id") to get data from the intent...

Answer (score 1):

SuperheroActivity

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
id = extras.getInt("id");
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.superheroText); 
text.setText(id+"");
```